# Adding Editable Custom Attribute in openAM using CLI

Tags: attributes, ldap, openam, opendj

I am trying to add a User Custom attribute in openam and it's embedded opendj. I followed their instructions in link :
https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/12.0.0/dev-guide/chap-custom-attr
which involves :

1. Updating Opendj Schema for the new attribute
2. Updating the iPlanetAmUserService with the new custom attribute
3. And to allow Users To Update the New Attribute, in OpenAM.

We want to automate this entire process using **cli**'s or by updating a file, I am able to achieve **Step 1 & 2** with cli. But for **Step 3**, it either requires control-panel or Apache Studio Directory which are GUI based. I am trying to find the best option to achieve the **Step 3** automation via cli or by updating configs. Appreciate your advices..

Answer (score 0):

If step 3 is about allowing Users to update the new Attribute in OpenAM, then I don't think the control panel nor Apache Directory Studio would help since both are using LDAP and talk directly to OpenDJ.
You might need to add the attribute to one of the OpenDJ ACI that states what can be modified by users. This can be done over LDAP using ldapmodify for example.
Now if the settings are in OpenAM, you should be able to use the amadmin CLI to do so.